# How to simulate user interaction when writing Tests for a Visualforce controller

Tags: unit-test

I have written test code for this controller but it only covers 9% of it. What do I need to do to cover the rest ? I'm really confused when it comes to testing VF controllers.

Here is the controller :

```
public class UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev {

    public String selectedType {get;set;}
    public Boolean selectedAwesomeness {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    private Vendor_Product_Review__c contact {get;set;} 
    public String fileName {get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody {get;set;}
    public Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c objBVar{get;set;}

    public String contactproduct {get;set;}

    public UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 
        this.contact = (Vendor_Product_Review__c)controller.getRecord();

        objBVar = new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c (Vendor_Product_Review__c = this.contact.id);

    }   

    // creates a new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c record

    private Database.SaveResult saveCustomAttachment() {


        //Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c obj = new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c();

        objBVar.Vendor_Product_Review__c = contact.Id; 
        objBVar.Vendor_Profile__c = contact.Vendor__c;
        objBVar.Vendor_Product__c = contact.Vendor_Product__c;
        objBVar.Description__c = description;
        objBVar.Document_type__c = selectedType;


        // fill out cust obj fields
        return Database.insert(objBVar);

    }

    // create an actual Attachment record with the Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c as parent


    private Database.SaveResult saveStandardAttachment(Id parentId) {

        Database.SaveResult result;

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.body = this.fileBody;
        attachment.name = this.fileName;
        attachment.parentId = parentId;
        // insert the attahcment
        result = Database.insert(attachment);
        // reset the file for the view state
        fileBody = Blob.valueOf(' ');
        return result;
    }

    /**
    * Upload process is:
    *  1. Insert new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c record
    *  2. Insert new Attachment with the new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c record as parent
    *  3. Update the Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c record with the ID of the new Attachment
    **/
    public PageReference processUpload() {

        if(description =='' & filebody==null)
                {
                ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 
                'You must include either a File or a Note.'));
                    return null;
                }


        /** if(description !='' & filebody==null)
                {        
                   Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();

                // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
                Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c customAttachment = [select id from Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];                
                update customAttachment;
                }
         **/   

         try {
            Database.SaveResult customAttachmentResult = saveCustomAttachment();

            if (!customAttachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                //ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                  //'Could not save attachment because either filebody was empty or the customAttachmentResult was unsuccessful.'));
                return null;
                system.debug('customattachmentresult **************!!! ');
                return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
            }

            if (filebody != null) {
                Database.SaveResult attachmentResult = saveStandardAttachment(customAttachmentResult.getId());

                if (attachmentResult == null || !attachmentResult.isSuccess()) {
                    //ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,
                      //'Could not save attachment.'));           
                    //return null;
                    return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
                } else {
                    // update the custom attachment record with some attachment info
                    Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c customAttachment = [select id from Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c where id = :customAttachmentResult.getId()];
                    customAttachment.name = this.fileName;
                    customAttachment.Attachment__c = attachmentResult.getId();
                    update customAttachment;
                }
            }
       } catch (Exception e) {
          ApexPages.AddMessages(e);
          return null;
       }

            return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
      }


    public PageReference back() {
        return new PageReference('/'+contact.Id);
    }     
}
```

And here is the test code I've written for it :

```
     @isTest(SeeAllData = false)

        private class TestUploadAttachControllerVendProdRev

            {    
                static testMethod void UnitTestUploadAttachControllerVendProdRev()

                     {     



                        Department__c dept = new Department__c();
                        dept.Name = 'Dept1';
                        dept.Department_Manager__c = '005i0000005o3zu';
                        insert dept;                

                        Vendor_Profile__c vprof = new Vendor_Profile__c();
                        vprof.Name = 'ABCProf';
                        vprof.Department_of_Record__c = dept.id;
                        vprof.Department_Manager__c = '005i0000005o3zu';
                        insert vprof;

                        Vendor_Product__c vprod = new Vendor_Product__c();
                        vprod.Name = 'ABCProd';
                        vprod.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
                        vprod.Reviewed_Vendor__c = vprof.id;
                        vprof.Department_of_Record__c = dept.id;
                        insert vprod;

                        Vendor_Product__c vprod2 = new Vendor_Product__c();
                        vprod2.Name = '123Prod';
                        vprod2.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
                        insert vprod2;

                        Vendor_Contract__c vc = new Vendor_Contract__c();
                        vc.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
                        vc.Products_Included__c = '[ABCProd,123Prod]';
                        insert vc ;

                        Vendor_Product_Review__c vrev = new Vendor_Product_Review__c();
                        vrev.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
                        vrev.Vendor_Product__c = vprod.id;
                        insert vrev ;



                       ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(vrev);
                       UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev up = new UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev(sc);

           public ApexPages.StandardController con {get;set;}



        public UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{ 
        this.contact = (Vendor_Product_Review__c)controller.getRecord();
        con = controller;
        objBVar = new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c (Vendor_Product_Review__c = this.contact.id);

    } 

    up.description('test');

        String nextPage = up.con.save().getUrl(); 


                 }

        }
```

Comment: So you have instantiated it. Do you expect the other methods to execute on their own. Treat testing just like you are replicating what is happening in the UI. think about the process. To do X then Y needs to execute and values A,B, and C need to be ..... Then write test code to do it and assert the results are as expected. You test code needs to actually cause something in your controller to happen for it to be "covered" and you need to asserted that the values in your controller and DB are correct in order for it to be "tested"

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out how to do that. As I said, I'm confused on how to do that with a VF controller. I don't know how to replicate the entry of an inputTextArea, or where to put it in the test code. I also don't know if I need to somehow save the page in order to initiate the controller. The other thing that makes it complicated is that a good portion of the code is oriented around filing the attachment. And I don't know how to replicate that in test code either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So, lets start small. Entry of an InputtextArea - in your test you simple set the value of the property (maybe `description `) that the inuputtext area is bound to to the value you want it to be. For the attachment, you create the file in your test and se nth properly that holds the attachment to that value. To simulate a button click, you execute the method that the button calls. Remove the UI from your mind and look at what it is doing and test that.

Comment: Thank you - I updated my test code to show what I am attempting. I am attempting to populate the description inputtextarea and then save the page but I'm getting a 'method does not exist or incorrect signature' error. I just want to populate something and save the page.

Comment: this goes in your controller not the test class `public ApexPages.StandardController con {get;set;}` - I mean this in the nicest way possible but  you really need to start reading / learning as I believe you do not have a solid understanding of the fundamentals. Nothing that we give you here will help you understand that, its just not designed to do it. It is just an exercise is code dumping.

Comment: See new answer - May be bugs in it, meant as an example. May or may not compile / pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems like you really want to learn so I have begun the code for you. There is room to do it better (frameworks, test data population, etc) but this will give you a starting point to understanding what needs to be done.

Keep in mind there maybe typos and is it not guaranteed to pass.

Also, once written and passing, **never** modify a test method to make it pass unless you are **absolutely** sure it is failing because the test method is written incorrectly. Many times people will update a test method when it fails so that it passes when the real issue was a change in the code that the test method caught and it should have failed.

The above is just an FYI......

So review the code below (All methods go in a test class), study it, use it as an example of what is happening and as a way to do things.

**basic Instantiation and end to end**

```
    private static testmethod void instantiateAndSaveAttachment(){

        //Query for records (other ways to cache it but for now this works)
        //Records are expected to be there from the TestSetup method
        Vendor_Product_Review__c exampleRecord = [Select ID From Vendor_Product_Review__c]; 
        Vendor_Profile__c exampleVendorProfile = [Select ID From Vendor_Profile__c];
        Vendor_Product__c exampleVendorProduct = [Select ID From Vendor_Product__c];

        ApexPages.StandardController ctrl = New ApexPages.StandardController(exampleRecord); //Instance of Standard Controller
        UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev con = New UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev(ctrl); //Instantiate Class

        //What happens when the controller is instantiated
            //this.contact = (Vendor_Product_Review__c)controller.getRecord();
            //objBVar = new Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c (Vendor_Product_Review__c = this.contact.id);
        //So we need to check that this did actually occur

        //Assert Instantiation set values as expected
        system.assertEquals(exampleRecord.id,con.contact.id,'The ID of the Vendor Record did not match the test record id');
        system.assertNotEquals(null,con.objBVar,'The Vnedor attachment record was not instantiated');
        system.addertEquals(exampleRecord.id,con.objBVar.Vendor_Product_Review__c,'the ID of the relationship was not as expected');

        //Next step, we need to simulate the action on the page that saves the attachment
        //Ask yourself, what is required, user has to populate fields and click a button
        //What fields need to be populated and where in the controller are the values stored

        //The saveAttachment starts with:
            //if(description =='' & filebody==null)
        //So we know we need values there

        //Create a blob to attach as a file
        Blob tmp = blob.valueOf('Test Blob text');

        con.description = 'Example Description'; //Set description as it is required in the IF blocks
        con.selectedType = 'test type';
        con.fileBody = tmp; //Set file body

        //Set values for objBVar record - See the saveCustomAttachment method
        con.contact.Vendor_Profile__c = exampleVendorProfile.id;
        con.contact.Vendor_Product__c = exampleVendorProduct.id;
        //......Remaning values......

        //Call the method, if there is an error null is returned
        system.assertNotEquals(null,con.processUpload(),'A Pagereference was not returned on save of attachment');
        //Eventually you will need test methods to cover the other if...then..else branches

        //now query for custom attachment and check values
        Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c[] customAttachment = [Select ID, Vendor_Profile__c, Vendor_Product__c from  Vendor_Product_Review_Attachment__c Where Vendor_Profile__c = :exampleRecord.id];

        system.assertEquals(1,customAttachment.size(),'There was not exactly one custom attachment created');
        system.assertEquals(con.selectedType,customAttachment[0].Document_type__c,'Document Type did not match selected type');

        //...Continuing on for the standard attachment
    }
```

**this tests an error condition**

```
private static testmethod void saveError(){
    Vendor_Product_Review__c exampleRecord = [Select ID From Vendor_Product_Review__c]; //Should be created

    ApexPages.StandardController ctrl = New ApexPages.StandardController(exampleRecord); //Instance of Standard Controller
    UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev con = New UploadAttachControllerVendProdRev(ctrl); //Instantiate Class

    //Assert that we have no messages
    system.assertEquals(false,ApexPages.hasMessages(),'We have page messages when we were not expecting them');

    system.assertEquals(null,con.processUpload(),'Method did not return null on error');

    system.assertEquals(true,ApexPages.hasMessages(),'We did not have any messages when we should have');
    system.assertEquals('You must include either a File or a Note.',ApexPages.getMessages()[0].getDetail(),'Error message not as expected');

}
```

**test Data Setup**

```
    @TestSetup
    private static setUpData(){
        Department__c dept = new Department__c();
        dept.Name = 'Dept1';
        dept.Department_Manager__c = '005i0000005o3zu';
        insert dept;                

        Vendor_Profile__c vprof = new Vendor_Profile__c();
        vprof.Name = 'ABCProf';
        vprof.Department_of_Record__c = dept.id;
        vprof.Department_Manager__c = '005i0000005o3zu';
        insert vprof;

        Vendor_Product__c vprod = new Vendor_Product__c();
        vprod.Name = 'ABCProd';
        vprod.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
        vprod.Reviewed_Vendor__c = vprof.id;
        vprof.Department_of_Record__c = dept.id;
        insert vprod;

        Vendor_Product__c vprod2 = new Vendor_Product__c();
        vprod2.Name = '123Prod';
        vprod2.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
        insert vprod2;

        Vendor_Contract__c vc = new Vendor_Contract__c();
        vc.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
        vc.Products_Included__c = '[ABCProd,123Prod]';
        insert vc ;

        Vendor_Product_Review__c vrev = new Vendor_Product_Review__c();
        vrev.Vendor__c = vprof.id;
        vrev.Vendor_Product__c = vprod.id;
        insert vrev ;

    }
```

Read the code like the user is on the UI. What do they enter, what do they click, what should happen, what should not happen etc. The replicate that via code. If they enter data, set the value that the field was bound to. If they click a button, call that method.

I usually start a test class with one method that tests instantiation and a simple end to end. I cover the logical branches, helper methods, errors, edge cases, etc in their own methods. If the simple end to end is a long process then I will not do this and will break up the method into smaller functional tests.

Notice the second test method. It is just as important to test error conditions and edge cases. Test null values, miskeyed data, and all other vulnerabilities of your code.

Test processes not lines of code. If two attachments are supposed to be created, create your test method to ensure two are created and with the correct values. If you just cover lines you may never know there is an issue and only 1 was created as lines can be covered with 1 roundtrip through a for loop.

Break tests up into small chunks of **unit testing**. It is perfectly fine to have a test method that just tests that a null value is handled in a single method of the controller. No need to do everything all in one method.

One final point. You will notice that my second test method did not assert the values on instantiation. It is because my first test method did so. No need to test it again unless I am specifically testing a different way to instantiate (Like no ID in the record used to create the standard controller).

Testing is a systematic and process driven effort. Doing it right will give you piece of mind when you make changes to your codebase and help to ensure that new changes do not cause old issues to reappear.

Another good tidbit, if you find a bug in normal use of your code, write a testmethod to replicate it, ensure it fails. Fix the bug, ensure the test passes. If you do thins routinely your tests become even more meaningful and will prevent the same bug from happening again.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric ! I really appreciate your help and patience. I learned a great deal from what you've shown me here. It's really the type of learning that is going to carry me forward.